# How do i add a message through a config in bukkit?

Tags: java, bukkit

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    if(sender instanceof Player) {
        Player  player = (Player) sender;
        if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("member")) {
            String member = "member " + player.getName();
            Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), member);
            player.sendMessage(getConfig().getStringList("MemberText"));
```

How do i make the player.sendMessage(getConfig().getStringList("MemberText")); work? An error message pops up when i try to post it.

Error: The method sendMessage(String) in the type CommandSender is not applicable for the arguments (List)

Answer (score 1):

I am not a Minecraft Modder, however, it appears as if `player.sendMessage()` expects a string, but the return type of `getConfig().getStringList("MemberText")` is that of type `List`.

Try converting your results to a string, or loop through, and `sendMessage` on each one of the items in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Either loop through the list and send every line, or if there is only one line of text in the config change `getConfig().getStringList("MemberText")` to `getConfig().getString("MemberText")`

[More on how to use the config here](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Configuration_API_Reference)

Answer (score 1):

You could loop threw all of the values in the config for `MemberText`, then send those, or one of those, to the player. for example:

```
List<String> memberTextMessage = new ArrayList<String>();
memberTextMessage = this.getConfig.getStringList("MemberText");
//we now have all of the strings under "MemberText"

for(int i = 0; i < memberTextMessage.size(); i++){
    //loop threw all the messages
    String s = memberTextMessage.get(i);

    player.sendMessage(s); //send the player the string
    //This will send them all of the messages under "MemberText" in the config
}
```

Just make sure to have a null check right before you assign `memberTextMessage` to what's in the config, just incase there's nothing under `MemberText` in the config, otherwise, you will get a `NullPointerException`:

```
if(this.getConfig.contains("MemberText"){
```

else, send the player a message saying there is nothing under `MemberText`, or, don't send them anything.